# Issue Android Studio 2.1.2: Fatal Exception: main Process java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-studio-2.1

So, I am doing this project that includes an intro activity that switches to a menu activity with navigation drawer. Couple of days ago, I had an issue switching from intro to menu (Android Studio 1.0.2: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException`) and it was solved by changing `name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` to `name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"` thanks to goonerdroid's suggestion in my previous link.

The issue that I have now is that I am trying to add a search action on the top right corner of the action bar alongside the navigation drawer so it can search on different future activities and javas that I will be adding. When I run the program, it enters the intro activity with no problems. When I click on the button to take me to the menuactivity, it displays the following error:

```
07-21 07:00:53.450 2775-2775/com.plateformeressources E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.plateformeressources, PID: 2775
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.plateformeressources.activity.LoginActivity$2.onClick(LoginActivity.java:87)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score -1):

in general, **NullPointerException** occures is when you try to use an object that has not been initialized with the ***new*** keyword or when you're trying to use empty string and do some thing with it.

Comment: Is not an answer, it's a comment.